# How to log where the copy has saved into a range

Tags: excel, vba, range, save-as

I would like to log to a cell where the copy of the workbook has been saved.

So far i have it saving but can't figure out how to log it

```
Sub CreateCopy()

Dim specialPath As String
Dim NameOfWorkbook As String
Dim FileName As String

specialPath = DownloadF & Range("HomeDB")

'FileCopy Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName, specialPath


NameOfWorkbook = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "R" & ".xlsm"

End Sub
```

I would like it to save to a range call test for the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sub will save the path for the workbook to the named range "test". It's code for the Mac version so you may need to adjust the file path definition.

```
Sub log()
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
With ThisWorkbook
    .Names.Add "test", r
    r = .Path & "/R" & ".xlsm"
End With
End Sub
```